# How to use the GPU with python-chess and chess-engine

Tags: analysis

I am working on a project to import a number of games as a PGN (game = chess.pgn.read_game(pgn)) and then iterate over each game and each move to evaluation the position with stockfish.  Using my computer CPU, it takes about 45 seconds to analyze each game.  I don't know much about running python on GPU but quick google search showed @jit before the evaluation function.  However, when trying to run, I get an error message saying @jit doesn't know the class chess.  Does anyone have any suggestions so I can try to run it on my GPU and speed up the process?  I can provide a .py script showing the exact code if necessary.

Comment: Stockfish cannot use GPU, see https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish/wiki/Stockfish-FAQ#can-stockfish-use-my-gpu

Comment: Python JIT compilation won't affect stockfish's perfromance since it's running highly optimized C++ code. Also most chess engines are CPU bound, except for maybe Leela.